# chrome in mobile render's the blank web page built using the angular js 1.5.X

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, web-applications, mobile-chrome

I have rewritten a web application using angularjs 1.5.X, when i loaded that with the chrome in desktop it works fine, Where if load the same url in mobile it renders blank white page 2/3 times, and there are no errors in the chrome console i checked using the chrome remote debugging option.